# ¿"Dense" o "Dénse"?

Tags: conjugación, acentuación

No encuentro una regla para justificar la sospecha de que *dense* (del verbo *dar*) lleva acento. De acuerdo con las reglas de la acentuación de palabras graves no lo lleva, pero lo he visto un par de veces con acento. Entonces, ¿cómo se escribe?

> Dénse un beso

O bien:

> Dense un beso

En diccionarios no lo he visto conjugado como lo necesito (y no tendría por qué aparecer ahí de hecho).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es *dense*.

No lleva acento gráfico actualmente por ser grave terminada en vocal, y tampoco llevaba con las viejas reglas, ya que *den* no lo lleva. En cambio *deles* antes llevaba acento gráfico y ahora no. La entrada *TILDE* del DPD, en la sección *4.3. Formas verbales con pronombres enclíticos* dice lo siguiente:

> A diferencia de lo establecido en normas ortográficas anteriores, a partir de la Ortografía académica de 1999 las formas verbales con enclíticos deben acentuarse gráficamente siguiendo las reglas de acentuación; así, formas como estate, suponlo, deles se escriben ahora sin tilde por ser palabras llanas terminadas en vocal o en -s, mientras que déselo, léela, fíjate llevan tilde por ser esdrújulas, y oídme, salíos, reírte, por contener un hiato de vocal cerrada tónica y vocal abierta átona.

Answer (score 2):

Dense es la respuesta correcta.

Pero...
Si estuvieras diciendo que dar algo a alguien, entonces llevaría un accento `dénselo`

Es porque sin el `lo` en el fin de `dense`, esa palabra obedece la regla que dice que el vocal penúltimo siempre lleva el estrés... si que ya no exista un accento en la palabra.